# Modelling Parent-Child Relationships with Classes

Tags: c#

I am working on a lightweight document management system and am looking for some help with how best to model certain relationships.  Essentially, I am working with two "organizational units": `Group`s and `Type`s.  When a group and a type are combined they form a `Link` with which `Document`s are then associated.  Note that a `Group` can be combined with more than one type, so for example you can have one `Link` composed of 'Group 1' and 'Type A' and a second `Link` composed of 'Group 1' and 'Type B'.  In my opinion this is not really the best way to have structured it but at this point I'm unable to alter it so I have to make do with what I'm given.

A `Document` can be a member of multiple `Link`s.  So for example, 'Document A' can be a member of 'Link 10' and 'Link 13'.

My issue is that sometimes I will want to display a single `Document` and list every `Link` that `Document` belongs to, and other times I will want to display a single `Link` and list every `Document` that belongs to that `Link`.

I'm not sure how to represent the relationship between these classes.  I've looked into the Composite Pattern but I don't think this will work for me because it seems to require that a child have only one parent, where in my case a child can have multiple parents.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780982/many-to-many-relationship-in-oop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is an n-to-m mapping. To be all OOP-y, you can store these mappings within each class:

```
// actually write it using properties, information hiding etc instead...
public class Document {
    public ICollection<Link> Links;
}

public class Link {
    public ICollection<Document> Documents;

    // this can be on Document as well, depending on what semantics you want...
    public void Add(Document d) {
        Documents.Add(d);
        d.Links.Add(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From a data perspective you are describing a many-to-many relationship, and those relationships generally require an entity representing the relationship itself.

So in your case, I would introduce the following object:

```
public class DocumentLink
{
    public Document Document { get; set; }
    public Link Link { get; set; }
}
```

Then each Document could have a collection of DocumentLink objects and each Link could have a collection of DocumentLink objects as well.

Of course, you could introduce helper methods to more directly retrieve all links for a document and all documents for a link, but this is the essential structure that I would use underneath.

Comment: This is how you'd build a database layout (a 'DocumentLink' table), but I think @thecoop has a more practical solution from an class-design point of view.  That is, of course, if there is no extra data required in the 'DocumentLink' entry (i.e. DateCreated), in which case this approach would be required.