# In Object Oriented Programming which object should maintain the many to many relationship? (if there is one)

Tags: php, oop, class, many-to-many

I'll use an example to illustrate this:

```
class Company {

}

class Person {

}
```

`Company` and `Person` hold a many to many relationship. A `Person` can belong to multiple `Companies` and a `Company` can hold multiple `People`.

Would I then need to create a third class:

```
class CompanyPerson {

}
```

or should the company handle it:

```
class Company {
    function add_person() {

    }
}
```

or maybe the `Person` should?

```
class Person {
    function add_to_company() {

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modelling Parent-Child Relationships with Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089582/modelling-parent-child-relationships-with-classes)

Answer (score 2):

The properties common to some random combination of a `Person` and `Company` instance can be modeled using an "association class".

There is a notation for this in UML, and it's not hard to create such a concept in an extensible programming language.

The idea is that any random pair of objects consisting of a `Person` and `Company` has a relationship, and that relationship is itself an object. It is neither `Person` nor `Company`, but the stuff associated with the connection between a particular `Person` and `Company` instance.

That stuff (properties, methods) constitutes a class: the `Person-Company` association class.

I made this work in Lisp before, with some macros for defining an association class for a given pair of classes, and a global weak hash table for mapping object pairs to their association class object (so that for a given person and company it was possible to retrieve the association, and that association would go away when these objects become garbage).

The actual link between particular companies and people is easy, using e.g. lists or other associative data structures. A person object can have a list of companies, and vice versa. The association class idea addresses the problem of where to put the person-company stuff. For example each `Person` has a role within a `Company` (let's say). We cannot have a `role` variable in a `Person` because it can have many roles w.r.t many companies. We certainly cannot have a `role` in the company because it's not even a person; it has people associated with it who have roles. The role can go into the association: problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

It totally depends on you usage scenario.

If you only ever need to find the people who work for a company, store the list of People on the Company; if you only ever need to find the companies that people work for then store it there.

Sooner or later you'll probably find you need to model the actual relationship Person<-->Company and you'll create a separate class to represent that.  Now you can handle adding properties like the date the employment began, the date it ended etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't think you need a third class.

Think of what an ORM (Doctrin for php, Hybernate forn java) does:

In this case on a databse layer you will have 3 tables:

Company, User and Company_user (join table beetween user and company that says which user beleongs to which company).

Also you can map this situation just with two db tables:

Company, user and in user you have an reference pointing to company. So based on this reference you can say the company the user belongs to.

Finally on a class design i think:

- Class companuy can hold an array of user (list of user belonging to the company)
- Class user can hold a reference to company (the company the user bleongs to)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the use case, but generally many to many object relationship can be deployed using a reference class

```
class CompanyPersonRelationship {
    public $company;
    public $person;
}
```

So now, both company and person can keeps track of their relationship lie

```
class Company {
   public $persons = array();   
}

class Person {
   public $companies = array();
}
```